# SQL ENCODING IN SQL Management studio

Tags: sql, sql-server, localization, character-encoding

We have  tri-lingual system  at work, english,greek and russian.
I have an issue with russian  when i update some of the fields in my database.
If i use an update query to update a field form the default english to russian i get '?????????' instead of the russian characters.if i update directly by hand it shown correctly.
Help!

Comment: Can you provide more information: Which version of SQL Server Mgmt Studio? What are your display settings, what do you mean by "update directly by hand", what are the character set settings on your tables and columns?

Comment: Hi sorry
I am using 2005, the collation of the DB is Greek_CI_AI. By hand i mean opening the table and editing the field directly.

Answer (score 5):

```
 step 1 : Use DATATYPE as NVARCHAR.
 Step 2 : put N before string your are inserting in your file 
          Example 

           insert into table( col1,col2) values (N'string1',N'string2')
```

will resolve your issue